# How to Set Location on Google Compute Image with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

How to set location (regional/multi-regional) on google compute image with terraform.?

[this is image location on google cloud console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRHx2.png)

i have google_compute_image with terraform:

```
resource "google_compute_image" "default" {
  name   = "myimage-release-2021"
  family = "myimage"

  #i need set location to regional here

  source_disk = "projects/${var.provider_project}/zones/${var.provider_zone}/disks/${var.instances.instance_name}"

}
```

thank u guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it is **not supported**. But there is already a github issue for that:

- [Allow setting the storage location for google_compute_image resource](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6082)